# Button to get href of link within same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a share on twitter link that grabs the href and text from the first (or previous) href in the div. I have multiple divs on the page so rather than write a script unique to each div id, I'd like the code to get the data from the div in which the link that is clicked sits and puts them in variables. How would I do this? The hrefs don't have ids.

```
<div id="genericID">
<a href="www.google.com">This is not a sentence.</a> 
<a href="https://twitter.com/share">Share on Twitter.</a> 
</div>
```

Comment: jquery prev() gets the previous whatever-you-need https://api.jquery.com/prev/

Comment: Something like `$(this).parent().find('a')` will get the first `<a>`.

Comment: We're assuming as you haven't included any attempts in the code you show above and have finished the question with "how would I do this?"  This makes the question too broad and therefore off topic for this site - read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you nothing better to do than make petty comments on a thread from someone who genuinely just wanted a little help? Others were kind enough to help without making any comment on the lack of evidence in my post that I had tried it myself before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
$("#genericID a").click(function(){  
  var firstLink = $(this).prev();
  var text = firstLink.text();
  var link = firstLink.attr("href");  
  alert("TEXT: " + text + "\nLINK: " + link);
});
```

Here is the example I used to test:
https://codepen.io/Parrigin777/pen/QaxyYZ

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<div id="hello">
  <a href="www.microsoft.com">test1</a>
  <a href="www.google.com">test2</a>
</div>
```

and for javascript:

```
$(this).parent().find('a').attr('href')
```

Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/6p1oL3zj/

This will throw an alert on click on all anchors within the div 'hello'.